# Mobile - Best way to dynamically add more fields to the form

Tags: forms, mobile, dynamic-ui

I have a form so the user can issue an invoice, it is basically composed of comboboxes and 90% of the time the user will send the receipt with only one product, but rarely it will send with more than one, my question is whats the "best way" I can add a button or something so the user can add (and remove) more products to the receipt.

My current form:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Would this work? It's not clear if the product is tied to any other fields like unit value or quantity but on the request to add additional products, this was my initial thought. 
[image: mobile phone invoice with the addition of an add another product cta]

Comment: Yes, the Unit Value and Quantity are tied to the product, so I will need to add these three fields product, unit value and quantity to the form

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to accomplish this and this is one of them. Here the user can edit each product, unit value, and quantity and also remove it easily if needed and add another product.

Note: The CTA at the bottom - I would encourage you to either change the text color to something dark or use a darker background as it is not WCAG compliant.

[image: comp of invoice with the product, unit value, and quantity on the same line]